# Eclipse 3.5 and Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, java-7

Is there any way where I can increase the Java Compiler Compliance level of Eclipse 3.5 to 1.7. (i.e.) By adding a plugin/add-on. Since by default this will not support the JDK 1.7 compliance.

We have a constraint in Eclipse upgrade, since it's an RCP application.

Any thoughts on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude, there is no way to enable Java 7 Compliance in Eclipse 3.5. Have to migrate to 3.7 at least. 
Thanks a lot for your responses.

Answer (score 11):

Old eclipse version doesn't support java 7. You will have to download at least eclipse-3.8M1 version.

Comment: You don't need to use a milestone build. Java 7 support is available for Eclipse 3.7.1 or higher.

Answer (score -1):

Windows --> Preferences --> Java -->  Installed JRE --> Add --> Standard VM --> Then Select the JDK 7 and set it as default.

Comment: I don't think just that would suffice. You'll also have to verify that `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler` has a compliance level of `1.7` set for all projects.

Comment: Yes, I think there no tool for update every project in to JDK 1.7 by one click.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
PLease check the image to change the setting make it your default under the Compiler setting.

Comment: Can you please detail the steps that you are referring to.

Comment: This will make the JRE setting to Java 7.But if you go to Compiler --> JDK Compliance --> Compliance level can only be set up to 1.6. But is there a way to set it to 1.7.