# How to add JDK 7 in compiler list in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rational-rsa

I have installed the JDK7 on my machine and I want it to add in the list of compiler [image]

I have tried adding JDK 7 in the list of installed JRE but it is still not appearing in the list of compiler compliance level.[image]

Could any one tell me how can I add JDK 7 into new compliance level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse uses its own compiler (see [What is the difference between javac and the Eclipse compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler)), so you won't find it if you use an old version of Eclipse (as probably your RSA is based on). Java 7 support is available for Eclipse 3.7.1 or higher (at the moment current stable is 4.2).

However, if you want to keep that version of Eclipse, you can create a new Builder using your JDK7 as base. To do this, go to Project and add a new Builder specifying where the javac is and the other options.

Look also at this question: [Eclipse 3.5 and Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847294/eclipse-3-5-and-java-7)

Comment: ok then is there any way I can update the eclipse automatically ?

Comment: Help menu, Check for update. But I do not know if it works for major releases (yes for minor). I cannot test it for you since I have latest major one.

Comment: Yes, it works for major releases, here's how to do it: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use the 3.8 version of eclipse to get Java 7 support. But I noticed that some later versions of 3.7.x might have it too.

See this for features:

http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/r3_8/Java7news/whats-new-java-7.html